# How can I fix localhost configuration error

Tags: php, sql-server, localhost

I'm trying to set up WordPress localhost and when I click to open installed app I get an error message "class not registered".

This started happening after I factory reset my laptop. Pleas what do I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question) 
to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure basic LAMP is installed. Probably you also have to edit your hosts file `/etc/hosts` with `127.0.0.1 your_site_url` starting from the new line. Also try edit/create index.php file and put there
`<?php phpinfo();`

Normally you should see your php config.